# How to link tables and figures in one Word Document to a separate word document in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I’m writing a paper in a MS Word document (Doc 1). This paper includes tables and figures. I like to keep my tables and figures in a separate Word document (Doc 2).

I’m wondering if is there a way I can “link” my references to tables and figures in Doc 1 to the actual tables and figures in Doc 2. Such that, the table and figure numbers in Doc 1 will update automatically as I move tables and figures around in Doc 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly insert your figures and tables as links in Doc 1. You would need to bookmark them in Doc 2 and then insert them as links with reference to the bookmarks.

Note that this is not exactly automatic in that:

1. In Doc 2 you need to be careful to preserve the bookmarks so that they refer to the figure or table you want to duplicate.
2. When something is changed in Doc 2, you need to tell Word to update the links in Doc 1. This can often be done by selecting all of the body of your document (**Ctrl+A**) followed by the **F9** key to update fields. *(On many computers you will need to use **Fn+F9**.)*

If these are common items to be shared in many documents, you would likely be better off storing them as [AutoText](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm) in a [Global Template](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Global) and using an AutoText Field to insert them in your production documents. *Links are to pages on my website.*

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it. This is going to make a big difference.